# Memory allocation Java Enum

Tags: java, enums

This question is regarding the memory allocation of objects which decalred inside enum,
   I have a Enum class as follows

```
 class TemplateEnum{

    F1(new Class1()), F2(new Class2()),F3(new Class3());
     /*
        Related code like constructors
     */
   }
```

My doubt is when the object gets created(memory allocated) for the classes `class1,class2,class3`.

Thanks

Comment: The object gets created when the `TemplateEnum` class is loaded.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : thanks, is that all the objects gets created at Enum load itself?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That should probably be an answer.

Comment: Java enum types are singleton and it allocates memory when the class is loaded.

Comment: @Jeffrey Yeah, took a few minutes to find references to write it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you meant

```
enum TemplateEnum {
    F1(new Class1()), F2(new Class2()),F3(new Class3());
    /*
    Related code like constructors
    */
}
```

The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2) states that

> In addition to the members that an enum type E inherits from Enum,
>   for each declared enum constant with the name n, the enum type has an
>   implicitly declared public static final field named n of type E. These
>   fields are considered to be declared in the same order as the
>   corresponding enum constants, before any static fields explicitly
>   declared in the enum type. Each such field is initialized to the enum
>   constant that corresponds to it.

Therefore `F1` (and the others) become

```
public static final TemplateEnum F1 = new TemplateEnum(new Class1());
```

[And since static fields are initialized when the class is loaded](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2), the `new Class1()` in each field's constructor call will be executed then.